# What is the xpath for the container of this HTML list?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, page-factory

Being unfamiliar with `JUnit`, I'm interested in [scraping data](https://github.com/THUFIR?tab=repositories) from a [website](http://books.toscrape.com/) -- at least for now.

I [see](https://gist.github.com/vanangelov/83ab133ca86ea1262c0437569990d0d2) that the fragment extends a base class:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class PageFragmentsExampleTest extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void shareSecondPost()  {
        FacebookSportPostsPage facebookPage = FacebookSportPostsPage.open();
        FacebookPostFragment secondPost = facebookPage.getPostByIndex(2);
        secondPost.share();
    }

    @Test
    public void sharePostFromDate()  {
        FacebookSportPostsPage.open().getPostByText("April 16 at 7:35am").share();
    }

}
```

but how is that fragment used?  It seems that the `container` is passed to the fragment constructor.

What is the `container` for the [books catalogue](http://books.toscrape.com/)?

Using `inspect element` I get an `xpath` of `/html/body/div/div/div/aside/div[2]/ul/li/a` for the "Books" link.

But, this is very different from the sample `xpath` String of

```
"//*[contains(text(),'%s')]//ancestor::div[@class='%s']", (text, POST_CONTAINER_CLASS)`
```

What is the `xpath` for the "Books" catalogue `container`?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Books" catalogue container*? What is your target element?

Comment: Learning the terminology here.  I think that the target element would be the list itself, if I understand correctly.  I'd like to "pull" out the relevant html, and pass only that fragment to a handler class (?) specific to that chunk.

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to use css selector which is reliable then xpath.

For Books link

1. .nav.nav-list css class points to all Books category. In css to use class name we use `.` before name of each class
2. move to first `li` tag using `>`. This means next inner child node.
3. move to first anchor `a` tag which is Books link

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".nav.nav-list>li>a")).click();
   ```

Comment: I've heard of speed advantages for `css` selector, but wasn't aware it could be more reliable as well.  Why more reliable?

Comment: @Thufir - I said css are more reliable then xpath, its a comparison. The reason is xpath is the hierarchy of HTML page in XML nodes structure, which changes frequently so making xpath more prone to failure, where as css are web page elements styling classes whose names does not change to frequently, making them more reliable.

Comment: @AmitJain , absolutely not :) I guess you're talking about *absolute XPath*, but actually *relative XPath* is more powerful and definitely not less reliable than CSS-selector

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `<div class="side_categories">` matched by XPath like

```
"//*[contains(text(),'%s')]//ancestor::div[@class='%s']", (text, POST_CONTAINER_CLASS)
```

you can try

```
"//*[normalize-space()='Books']//ancestor::div[@class='side_categories']"
```

Comment: weird usage for "class", but okay.  Leaving open until I get cracking on writing actual code.

Comment: @Thufir , if you want to select *unordered list* (`ul`) with book categories, try `//div[@class="side_categories"]//ul[not(@class)]`

Answer (score 1):

Xpath for link book categories

```
//li/ul/li/a
```

Xpath for book items

```
//ol/li
```

Comment: beautifully simple.  My speed ;)